# Query on regexp using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on regexp where if the user enter consecutive spaces, dashes, apostrophes then I have to show one error message

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]{0,}$
```

With the above reg exp I am getting if the user enter one dashes I am getting error but here I want spaces apostrophes.

Comment: Do you want something like [`^(?!.*( {2}|--|''))[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._ '-]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/F0bK6X/1)?

Comment: thanks for the answer i want only for consecutive spaces,-----' not for letter

Comment: See [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLtLxnep/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, basically you have to do Back-referencing in order to check for double words (or more than doubles)

```
/(\s-,)\1+/.test(...)
```

```js
const hasDoubles = new RegExp(/(\s|-|,)\1+/);

console.log( hasDoubles.test("hello - ") ) // false
console.log( hasDoubles.test("--") ) // true
console.log( hasDoubles.test("  ") ) // true
console.log( hasDoubles.test(",,") ) // true
```

This code captures any space `\s` or dashes `-` or `,` then checks if it occurs again 1 or more times denoted by `\1+` the `\1` for back-referencing the capture group, and `+` for 1 or more occurances.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but when i try in regex online i am not getting the result let say for exmple if i am typing consecutive ----- or spaces or """""""

Comment: can you send me a link? because i tried an online solution and all the consecutive cases match(or the console). `-------` does match it all for example.

Comment: youre missing a `(` in the beginning, here a working link https://regex101.com/r/F0bK6X/3

Comment: also you didnt mention quotes, you said apostrophes. anyways, here is another link with double quotes check, you can add whatever you want if you got the pattern https://regex101.com/r/F0bK6X/4

Comment: Thanks for your help but this was not considering space how to include space for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147542/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-ahmad-bamieh).